# Controller ref not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In my SenchaTouch 2.3.1 app I have build a login panel for the user. It looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.loginPanel',

requires: [
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Password',
    'Ext.Button'
],

config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Business Login',
            itemId: 'login',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    itemId: 'email',
                    label: 'E-Mail',
                    name: 'email',
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    itemId: 'password',
                    label: 'Passwort',
                    name: 'password',
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'loginButton',
            cls: 'button-blue',
            text: 'Login'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'loggedInPanel',
            cls: 'logged-in-panel',
            tpl: [
                'Sie sind eingeloggt als {firstname} {lastname} (ID: {agentId})'
            ],
            hidden: true,
            margin: '10 0'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

In my controller, I want to use a reference to this panel like this:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        loginPanel: 'loginPanel',
        navigationView: '#morenavigation',
        loggedInPanel: '#loggedInPanel',
        loginButton: '#loginButton'
    }
}
```

In the launch function of the controller, I want to check if the user already logged in to show his id and show a logout button. But when I try to get the panel ref, it's undefined. But why?

```
launch: function() {
    var me = this,
        sessionInfo = Ext.getStore('SessionInfo');

    console.log(me.getLoginPanel()); <-- undefined

    if (null !== sessionInfo.getAt(0).get('sessionId')) {
        me.successfullLogin(sessionInfo.getAt(0).get('sessionId'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of using the ref in my example would be:

```
refs: {
    loginPanel: {
        autoCreate: true,
        forceCreate: true,
        xtype: 'loginPanel'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is anything actually creating an instance of your view?

Inside your application's `launch` method, you'll probably have to create an instance of it, and then either give your view the `fullscreen: true` config, or add it to the viewport.  The examples on the Sencha Touch API docs for `Ext.app.Application` have the main view being created from the application's launch function.

Comment: This answer brought me to the correct way of using the ref. Thank you very much! You can use advanced refs in the controller with autoCreate and forceCreate options. See: [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/controllers-section-refs-and-control)